# Upload file with node js and store form information in database(mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, forms

I'm building a website where user needs to fill a form with information as first name, last name, profile picture, number etc... I've already code the form and I'm looking a way with node js to upload the image in a specific directory (or a default directory) and store the information that the users filled in my database. I use node js and Express with mysql.

UPDATE:

(I used formidable package and util package).
Please notice that for the image part, I only need the path( you will see it on the ouput section).

form code:

```
<form method="post" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
       <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" required /><br/>
       <label for="Prenom">Prénom: </label>
       <input type="text" name="user_prenom" id="Prenom" required /><br/>
       <label for="Nom">Nom: </label>
       <input type="text" name="user_nom" id="Nom" required /><br/>
       <label for="Mail">E-Mail: </label>
       <input type="email" name="user_mail" id="Mail" required/><br/>
       <label for="Pays">Pays: </label>
       <input type="text" name="user_pays" id="Pays" required/><br/>
       <label for="Ville">Ville: </label>
       <input type="text" name="user_ville" id="Ville" required/><br/>
       <label for="Num">Numéro: </label>
       <input type="tel" name="user_telephone" id="Num" /><br/>
       <input type="submit"  />
  </fieldset>
 </form>
```

handle:

```
router.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
processFormFieldsIndividual(req, res);
});

function processFormFieldsIndividual(req, res) {
//Store the data from the fields in your data store.
//The data store could be a file or database or any other store based
//on your application.
var fields = [];
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.uploadDir = "/public/photo_utilisateurs";
//Call back when each field in the form is parsed.
form.on('field', function (field, value) {
    fields[field] = value;
});
//Call back when each file in the form is parsed.
form.on('file', function (name, file) {
    fields[name] = file;
    //Storing the files meta in fields array.
    //Depending on the application you can process it accordingly.
});

//Call back for file upload progress.
form.on('progress', function (bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
    var progress = {
        type: 'progress',
        bytesReceived: bytesReceived,
        bytesExpected: bytesExpected
    };
    //Logging the progress on console.
    //Depending on your application you can either send the progress to client
    //for some visual feedback or perform some other operation.
});

//Call back at the end of the form.
form.on('end', function () {

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'content-type': 'text/plain'
    });
    res.write('received the data:\n\n');
    res.end(util.inspect({
        fields: fields
    }));
});
// var user = JSON.parse(fields);
// connection.query('INSERT INTO Utilisateurs (user_nom, user_prenom, user_mail, user_phone, user_pays, user_ville) VALUES ("' + user.user_nom + '", "' + user.user_prenom + '", "' + user.user_mail + '", "' + user.user_pays + '", "' + user.user_ville + '", "' + user.user_telephone + '")',
//     function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
//         if (err) throw err;
//         else res.send('success');
// });
form.parse(req);
}
```

**The Output**

received the data:

```
{ fields: 
    [ user_prenom: 'dfw',
      user_nom: 'efwe',
      user_mail: 'efew@fref',
      user_pays: 'efwe',
      user_ville: 'efwe',
      user_telephone: '4380564324',
      image: File {
      domain: null,
      _events: {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      size: 518,
      path: '/tmp/upload_e611ea0745206682b26c208d816dc604',
      name: '1462507431_play_now_sign_youtube_video.svg',
      type: 'image/svg+xml',
      hash: null,
      lastModifiedDate: Mon May 09 2016 00:16:24 GMT-0400 (EDT),
     _writeStream: [Object] } 
    ] 
  }
```

Comment: can u show the code of your form and form handeling

Comment: sure give me 5 minutes please

Comment: Please notice that for the Image, I only need the path

Comment: its seems working where u get the problem? if u want only the path the Use `__dirname` after that your image folder name

Comment: Yes it work I just want to know how to get every single information. As you see on the output section, it return a json object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111374/discussion-between-akhilesh-singh-and-anonym).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply declare the Global variable and assign the form fileds to it. And use it where you want.

```
var data = util.inspec({
    data: fields
      });
    console.log(data);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
form.on('end', function () {

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'content-type': 'text/plain'
    });
    res.write('received the data:\n\n');


   // console.log(fields.name+'-'+fields.nickname);
    var values={
          name:fields.name,
          nickname:fields.nickname,
          email:fields.email,
          password:fields.password,
          dob:fields.dob,
          gender:fields.gender,
          phoneno:fields.phone
      };

    connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', values, function(err,req,res){
                        if(err){
                          console.log('Connection result error '+err);

                        }
                            else{
                        console.log('Success');     

                            }
                });

               res.end();  
});
```

Comment: To read the form fields from ajax+jquery to nodejs and save into mysql DB